# How to fill my circle(CGContextAddArc) with a different color?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have the following but it only draws the border of a circle.
I would like to fill the circle. ??

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextAddArc(context, 50, 50, 50, 0, 30, 0);

//set the fill or stroke color
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1.0);

//fill or draw the path
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **CGContextFillPath** to fill the path.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the stroke related lines and use only fill related lines.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextAddArc(context, 50, 50, 50, 0, 30, 0);

//set the fill or stroke color
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);

//fill or draw the path
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
```

If you want only a circle

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextAddArc(context, 50, 50, 50, 0, 30, 0);

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1.0);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
```

Answer (score 1):

For filling solid color it should have `kCGPathFill` in `CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);`

For stroke with color it should have `kCGPathStroke` in `CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);`

Something like this:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextAddArc(context, 50, 50, 50, 0, 30, 0);

//set the fill or stroke color
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);

//fill on drawn path
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGContextAddArc(ctx, x, y, 1.0, 0, 2 * Pi, 1); // Or is it 2 * M_PI?

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, fillColor);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, strokeColor);
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);;
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to fill the circle you can use this**

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextAddArc(context, 50, 50, 50, 0, 30, 0);

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);

CGContextFillPath(context);
```

**and this code below used to draw the border for circle**

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextAddArc(context, 50, 50, 50, 0, 30, 0);

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1.0);

CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

**so, in this case you must to choose the first choice to fill the circle**

Answer (score 0):

Fill path:

```
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextAddArc(context, self.bounds.width/2, self.bounds.height/2, 150, 0, CGFloat(2 * M_PI), 0)
    UIColor.redColor().setFill()
    CGContextFillPath(context)
```

circle:

```
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextAddArc(context, self.bounds.width/2, self.bounds.height/2, 150, 0, CGFloat(2 * M_PI), 0)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10)
        UIColor.greenColor().set()
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
```