# How to make CGContextDrawPath draw on a nested subview?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm new to `context` concept in Apple iOS programming. Currently, I'm thinking in `views`. I want to draw an arc using the easiest method possible, and then I found this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905925/how-to-fill-my-circlecgcontextaddarc-with-a-different-color). But then I'm confused with context concept. I thought to draw something, I will need to call the drawing function and supply the `view` where I want the drawing function to draw. But in there, I got confused with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`. What "current context" is that? Is it the `UIScreen.mainScreen()`? How if I want to set the "current context" to a view inside a `UICollectionViewCell`, so that all the pixel drawn will be relative to the view? Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you draw in CocoaTouch is to subclass `UIView` to create a custom view and implement the `drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method. Put your drawing code inside `drawRect`. Something like:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(rect, NULL);
   [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
   CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
   CGContextAddPath(context, path);
   CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
   CGPathRelease(path);
 }
```

You can put your custom UIView inside of a UICollectionViewCell if you want.

Comment: Wait, so I subclass the `UIView` (for ex: `WOWView`) and then the view on the storyboard I set the class as `WOWView` ?

Comment: And ignore the `rect` parameter to drawRect. It's only used as an optimization in complicated views.

Comment: Hi, just want to ask again a little, can I draw two circle in the same view? For example, I want to draw a donut. So within a same view, I draw an outer circle with color blue, and then I draw a smaller circle in the center with color white. Is that possible? What I did is that I duplicate the code to draw the first circle (except the line to get current context) and paste below it, and then I change the radius and fill color. Is this the correct method to do that?

Comment: Oh sorry, it can. I just have a mistake in my implementation and think that I can only draw one shape. Thanks!